# Why does my function filter out zeroes as well as strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

I am trying to filter out all the strings in an array but the way I am doing it, it is also filtering out 0. I used filter() and a for loop/delete to try this but the zero gets removed every time.

this is my attempt at filtering with a for loop (filter() used to removed the empty array elements):

```
function filterArray(arr) {
    let newArr = arr;
    for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof newArr[i] === "string"){
                delete newArr[i];
        }
    }
    newArr = newArr.filter(Boolean);
    return newArr;
}
```

the test case that is not working is (all other test cases are working properly):

```
filterArray([1, "a", "b", 0, 15]);
```

this should return [1, 0, 15] but instead it is returning [1,15]. also, when I test `console.log(typeof arr[3]);` it returns "number" so I didn't think it would get deleted based on my if statement.

I appreciate any help/clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newArr.filter(Boolean)` uses the Boolean function to convert each value to a boolean value and then filters out any that are false.

```
Boolean(1)
> true
Boolean(0)
> false
Boolean(15)
> true
```

Thus you are left with `[1, 15]`.

A simpler way to do this...

```
function filterArray(arr) {
    return arr.filter(x => typeof(x) !== 'string');
}

filterArray([1, "a", "b", 0, 15]);
> [1, 0, 15]
```

As a sidenote - (`newArr = arr;`) doesn't duplicate the original array.

Comment: thank you! i tried the filter() way first but i must have messed something up. much appreciated.

Comment: also, thank you for the side note. I will use slice to copy the array .

Answer (score 0):

Also you can match numbers by regExp.

```js
var arr = [1, "a", "b", 0, 15];
var str = arr.join(" ");
console.log(str);
console.log(str.match(/\d+/g));
```